# custom rule for custom AD attribute in User Profile Sync settings

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, profile-sync

There is custom AD attribute `gender`. 
When setting up custom user profile property for that attribute (called `Gender`), is there any way to add custom rule, like this (pseudocode):

```
if (adUser["gender"] == "male") userProfile["Gender"] = "M"
if (adUser["gender"] == "female") userProfile["Gender"] = "F"
if (adUser["gender"] == "m") userProfile["Gender"] = "M"
```

Sure, I can create custom TimerJob that would do manual sync only with this attribute, but looking for a simple and embed solution first.

Comment: Is there a way to override User Profile Proxy provider/ some of it's classes responsible for property resolving?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, no. With Microsoft Identity Manager, you could do this, but that is attacking the problem with a large and complicated tool.

What I would suggest is just creating the User Profile Property, importing 'gender', and making sure 'gender' is consistent in Active Directory, *or* on the consuming side (whatever process in SharePoint is using this), just re-interpret the value appropriately.

Comment: I had no control over customer's AD. Actually, customer did (breaking) change - had been replaced "Male" to "M" and "Female" to "F".

Comment: Then I would handle that within whatever process is consuming those properties, as other options are heavyweight.